# Access virtual host without domain pointing to it

Tags: redirect, dns, ip, virtualhost, host

I have a domain which pointed to an IP address (A). This IP address hosts several other websites with their domains. I now forwarded this domain to another host but I also need to access the old site which now does not have a domain pointing to it. Of course I can't just access the old site by typing the IP address into the browser. How can I do it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on unix, you should modify the `/etc/hosts` file; `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` if you're on Windows. (This will likely require admin privileges.)

This overrides the public DNS which would otherwise map an IP to a domain name. The change tells your machine that the old IP address is the location of `example.com`, where your hosts file has a line that reads:

```
xxx.xx.xx.xx example.com www.example.com
```

And `xxx.xx.xx.xx` is your old server's IP.

Remember to comment out or remove the line when you're done! You may confuse your future self, otherwise!

Comment: Thanks. I already tried that but it still redirects to the new destination!?

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if you could review the output of `curl -vI http://example.com` and tell me if you see your old IP in there?

Comment: Additionally - and I've just updated the answer to reflect this - make sure `www` is also remapped in the `hosts` file!

Answer (score 0):

**"Host"** Header in HTTP is used to identify which of the many websites to visit on a virtual hosting web server. Virtual hosting is when a single IP address hosts websites(http content) for many different domains.

`For eg. "Host: www.example.com"`

You will find such a header in all virtual hosting websites.

Use an extension like [Tamper chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tamper-chrome-extension/hifhgpdkfodlpnlmlnmhchnkepplebkb?hl=en) to add `Host` to the header. Specify your domain name in this header.

Illustration -
The university in which I studied uses virtual hosting, hence using `Host` header is imperative.
See the following image.

[image: BVCOEND university home page]

Now, if I type the IP address (obtained from ping utility) directly. You see a default page.

[image: default server page]

[image: ping utility]

Now If I use tamper chrome extension to add `Host` header.
[image]

We can see that it lands on a page on `bvcoend.ac.in` domain.
[image]

I have to polish it further so that the landing page is the home page, but this process captures the essence of `Host` header used in `virtual hosting`.

**Update** : Using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to modify `Host` header seems to work fine for me, somehow tamper chrome isn't doing it's job perfectly (miss the good old Firefox Tamper data days).